# Pygame display does not open

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a flappy bird game with python (pygame). However, when I run my python script (used pygame) the window/display does not open. I have tried various solutions but nothing really worked. Everything is all in one map on my desktop. I use sublime text.

```py
import pygame
import neat
import time
import os
import random

WIN_WIDTH = 600
WIN_HEIGHT = 800

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "pipe.png")))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "base.png")))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bg.png")))

class Bird:
IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
MAX_ROTATION = 25
ROT_VEL = 20
ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def init_(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.velocity = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.image_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.velocity = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0 #time in jump
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2 #how much movement up/down
        if d >= 16:
            d = 16;

        if d <0:
            d-= 2

        self.y = self.y + d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win): #bird flapping up and flapping down
        self.img_count += 1 #keep track of for how long we have shown a certain image

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            slef.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            slef.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            slef.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            slef.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2 #when flapping up again it starts with showing IMGS2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.image.get_rect(topleft= (self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.form_surface(self.img)

def draw_window(win, bird):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0,0))
    bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    bird = Bird(200, 200)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()


    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
                run = False #get it out of the loop
        bird.move()        
        draw_window(win, bird)


pygame.quit() #quit the game
quit()
```

When I replace from "Run = True" till the end with:

```
    (width, height) = (1000, 700)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.update()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

It does show a black window. I have been struggling with this quite a lot but have not found a solution. I do not have a lot of python experience.

Comment: `__init__` instead of `init_`. See [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Furthermore you have to call `main()` somewhere.

Comment: `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:` rather than `if event.type == pygame.QUIT():`.  Note, `pygame.QUIT` is a constant. `pygame.QUIT()` would try to invoke `pygame.QUIT`

Comment: Hi Rabbid, thank for the help! However, it still does not show any display..

Comment: You have to read the error messages. I'm very sure there are some more errors.

Comment: I don't get any error message

Comment: Of course you'll get error messages. e.g. `self.vel`  is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

solved it! this is my code:

```
import pygame
import neat
import time
import os
import random

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("desktop/Flappy Bird/imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("desktop/Flappy Bird/imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("desktop/Flappy Bird/imgs", "bird3.png")))]
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("desktop/Flappy Bird/imgs", "pipe.png")))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("desktop/Flappy Bird/imgs", "base.png")))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("desktop/Flappy Bird/imgs", "bg.png")))


class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y): # was init_
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0 #time in jump
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2 #how much movement up/down

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y = self.y + d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win): #bird flapping up and flapping down
        self.img_count += 1 #keep track of for how long we have shown a certain image

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2 #when flapping up again it starts with showing IMGS2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft= (self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

def draw_window(window, bird):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0,0))
    bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    print('test1')
    bird = Bird(200, 200)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    run = True
    print("test")
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        bird.move()
        draw_window(win, bird)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()
main()
```

Comment: I don't think you need the last two rows in main. if you got there then pygame.quit() already happend inside your while loop. you could add sys.quit() if you want to close the window - you'll need to import sys first